# Vim: Placing (,) in between CERTAIN high numbers Issue

Tags: regex, vim, vi, substitution

source txt file:

```
34|Gurla Mandhata|7694|25243|2788|NalakankarÂ Himalaya|30Â°26'19"N
81Â°17'48"E|Dhaulagiri|1985|6 (4)|China
```

command input:

```
:%s/\(\d\+\)\(\d\d\d\)/\1,\2/g
```

command output:

```
34|Gurla Mandhata|7,694|25,243|2,788|NalakankarÂ Himalaya|30Â°26'19"N
81Â°17'48"E|Dhaulagiri|1,985|6 (4)|China
```

Desired output:

```
34|Gurla Mandhata|7,694|25,243|2,788|NalakankarÂ Himalaya|30Â°26'19"N
81Â°17'48"E|Dhaulagiri|1985|6 (4)|China
```

**Basically** `1985` is supposed to be `1985` and not `1,985`. I tried to put a `\?` so every time the pattern matches it stops and a `°+` after so it has to detect a `°` to match the pattern, but no success. It just replaces the `°` and everything before that, complete mess.

My knowledge of regular expressions however combined with the substitute is weak and I'm stuck here.

**EDIT**

the first 3 numbers represent heights of mountains, those 3 need to change with a (,) and the last number ( 1985 ) represents a year, which must not be changed.
Mathematical solutions are not going to work as loophole since there are mountains with a height off less than 1900

Comment: How does `1985` differentiate from `7694`, `25243`, and `2788`?

Comment: could a number > 1 million?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us what is the difference between `1985` and other numbers, so I assumed that your "small" numbers are less than 2000.

You almost got it:

```
:%s/(\d*[2-90])(\d\d\d)/\1,\2/g
```

Alternatively if that isn't what you want, you can use `c` flag (`:h s_flags`):

```
:%s/\(\d\+\)\(\d\d\d\)/\1,\2/gc
```

Comment: Your code would be correct IF I didn't have mountains with a height of less than 2000. My question was a bit vague, I'll rephrase my question

Answer (score 0):

this line will leave the last 3 columns untouched, just do substitution on the content before it:

```
%s/\v(.*)((\|[^|]*){3}$)/\=substitute(submatch(1),'\v(\d+)(\d{3})','\1,\2','g').submatch(2)/g
```

Note that the above line will change `1000000` into `1000,000` instead of `1,000,000`. Vim's `printf()` doesn't support `%'d`, it is pity. If you do have number > 1m, we can find other solutions.

### update

[image]

Comment: Surprisingly it gave the same result as my code. Do you know if vim is capable of only replacing a number of patterns? My problem is actually nothing more than replacing 3/4 patterns, it sounds so simple.

Comment: @RobVanMeirvenne added an animation to show that it **doesn't** give the same result as your codes. Your input is single line, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself, by using 3 seperate commands; one for every number string in the file:

`%s/^\(\d*|[^|]*|\)\(\d\+\)\(\d\d\d\)|/\1\2,\3|/g
:%s/^\(\d*|[^|]*|\d\+,*\d*|\)\(\d\+\)\(\d\d\d\)|/\1\2,\3|/g
:%s/^\(\d*|[^|]*|\d\+,*\d*|\d\+,*\d*|\)\(\d\+\)\(\d\d\d\)|/\1\2,\3|/g`

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to use `perl`:

```
:%!perl -F'\|' -lane 'for(@F[2..4]) { s/(\d+)(\d{3})/\1,\2/;} print join "|", @F'
```